# How do i find the author of table in hive?

Tags: database, hive

i am trying to figure out who created the table in hive. How can i obtain this info? i have tried

```
describe extended <tablename>
```

but it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

it should work. When i ran above command, i can see the information is under `Detailed Table Information`.

You can see in below screnshot, the owner is the owner of the table/view.

[image: screenshot]